# Mapping 'application/zip' to a ClientResponse with WebFlux

Tags: spring, amazon-s3, spring-webflux, reactive-programming

I'm pretty new to WebFlux and reactive API. I decided to rewrite Feign to Spring declarative client and it was a pretty smooth refactoring except for one particular case where I was downloading a ZIP file from an external system to back it up on S3. Even though the archive file is not large (some PDFs) I decided to play around a bit with WebFlux and imagined that it could be a nice workflow to just stream the data directly from the service's response to S3, for example, using `Flux<>` of some kind of data chunk - let's say a `DataBuffer`. Then I learned that in most cases S3 requires specifying the length of the content (I'm currently using SDK v2) and writing a flux of buffers (through an async S3 client) fails on checksum validation.
I thought, OK, the service provides `Content-Length` so it should be no problem to pass it through along with the flux but I stumbled upon not being able to map the response to the `org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ClientResponse`:

```
Content type 'application/zip' not supported for bodyType=org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ClientResponse
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type 'application/zip' not supported for bodyType=org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ClientResponse
    at app//org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyExtractors.readWithMessageReaders(BodyExtractors.java:205)
    Suppressed: The stacktrace has been enhanced by Reactor, refer to additional information below: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Body from GET http://localhost:49773/v2.1/accounts/123/envelopes/90dc747f-1dc8-4a4d-9a6d-913f82f0fa78/documents/archive [DefaultClientResponse]
Original Stack Trace:
```

Do I miss something? Is there a limited number of response types that one can map to the `ClientResponse`? I've read a bit about the S3 and maybe a multipart upload would be a way to go but I'd like to know if there was a simpler solution to that.

Or maybe I should map to something different than `ClientResponse`? Is there an object that gives access to both the flux of data and response headers?

I tried different mapping of the declarative HTTP client like the mentioned `ClientResponse` but also the `Flux<DataBuffer>` and integration with the S3 async upload. I believe that the declarative client causes no issues here but I have not checked the raw `WebClient`.

Since there was a request for more code.

The client method

```
@GetExchange("/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/archive")
    ClientResponse getEnvelopeInZipFormat2(
            @PathVariable("accountId") String accountId, @PathVariable("envelopeId") String envelopeId,
            @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers);
```

I created a simple isolated test case showing that I'm unable to map `application/zip` to client response - https://github.com/ksiczek/webflux-application-zip

Comment: Please show your code and what you tried to achieve instead of just a description and the resulting error.

Comment: @m-deinum thank you for your attention. I've added some code, I hope that helps. The ultimate goal was to stream 'application/zip' from the HTTP service to the S3 bucket. I figured out that I needed to provide the length for S3 and tried using something generic like `ClientResponse` but failed due to the content type.

Comment: I thought you retrieved something and tried to send it? It is unclear to me what is throwing the exception? The calling of the http proxy or the retrieval? Could you include all parts that are relevant instead of just parts and please also the full stacktrace as that will contain information.

Comment: @M.Deinum I understand, but to provide more code I'd need to carefully obfuscate it as I do not own it. The thing is that to work with the S3, I need the content length, but I cannot map to `ClientResponse` if it is `application/zip`. The stack trace is simply from the test method showing that one cannot use `ClientResponse` hence I do not know how I get the length.

Comment: The stacktrace isn't from the test method as it will include some internals from Sprng on were it fails. As stated it is unclear to me what part of the test this is. You made the impression that you are reading a stream with a regular `WebClient` (converting things yourself) and use an Http Client to send it to S3. But apparently it is the other way around?

Comment: Not going to argue where the stack trace comes from or what I'm actually trying to do. Could you please have a look and tell me why tests fail for this - https://github.com/ksiczek/webflux-application-zip?

Comment: I;m not going to checkout and analyze your code (unless you hire me to do so). So please include the requested information in the question.

Comment: Judging from the Spring documentation it isn't an allowed return type to return the `ClientResponse`. I wonder if a `ResponseEntity<DataBuffer>` or `ResponseEntity<byte[]>` would work. Although that would probably consume it and place the zip in memory. All in all you might be better of using a `WebClient` instead of the declarative `HttpClient`.